# Simplify $\frac{4\sin\alpha-5\cos\alpha}{3\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha}$

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify $\dfrac{4\sin\alpha-5\cos\alpha}{3\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha}.$

I think we should get $\cot\alpha$ which is $\dfrac{\cos^2\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha}.$ So I tried to write $\sin\alpha$ as $\sqrt{1-\cos^2\alpha}$ but it didn't work.

Comment: The cotangent function $\cot \alpha$ is defined to be $\cot \alpha = \frac{\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}.$. I think that is what you meant to write ...

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: My best bet is that you (in order to reduce to cot or tan) want to use the identity at the top of this page: https://www.myphysicslab.com/springs/trig-identity-en.html to reduce the numerator to a single sine and the denominator to a single cosine. This doesn't simplify. ($-\sqrt{\frac{41}{10}}\frac{sin\left ( x+arctan\left ( -\frac{5}{4} \right ) \right )}{cos\left ( x+arctan\left ( -3 \right ) - \frac{\pi }{2} \right )}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Weierstrass relations for double angles. Let

$$ \alpha = 2 \beta , t = \tan \beta,\; \sin \alpha= \dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}=S,\; \cos \alpha= \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=C;\;$$

When we simplify
$$ \dfrac{4C-5S}{3S-C}$$

we get in terms of tan half angle $t$

$$-\dfrac{5t^2+8t-5}{3t^2+2t-3}$$

but not

$$ \dfrac{1-t^2}{2t}= \cot \alpha $$

as you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't understand what you have written. What do you want to show me with it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hope this is now clear. I want to show you that simplification does not result in cotα.There may be a print error in the text-book or in the source you got it from.